# Flutter Firebase - Retrieve array & map data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my dataset :

[image: Firebase dataset]

I am trying to get this type of data in my app 1st I use an array and in the array i add map data and my value but i don't get any data.

My code

```
child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("coin").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Loder();
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.document.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.documents[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(map.values.toList()[index]["coinlink"]),
              );
            },
          );
        }),
```

**EDIT 1**

I got this error I need data from coinlink title and img

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,
> dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>,
> AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#29591):
> Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'document'.

How to get this type of data?

Comment: You're missing an `s` after `document` here: `itemCount: snapshot.data.document.length,`. So it should be `itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,`

Answer (score 0):

You need column inside list of display multiple coinLinks.

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.document.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  final  coinLinks = map["coinLink"] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>;
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Column(
                          children: coinLinks.map((coinLink){
                                  return Text(coinLink["title"]);
                             }).toList()
                     ),
                  );
                },
              );
```

Comment: and how to get the title & images from coinlink its throw error

Comment: You can retrive image like title in example

Comment: "Iterable<text>" can't be assigned to parameter type 'List<Widget>' why this comes

Comment: check now, its because map return iterable not a list

Comment: still no data error is dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>,
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#ee8af):
Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'document'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'